# Where can I ask questions regarding Nanotechnology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I have a few questions I want to ask that have to do with nanotechnology. There is no Stack Exchange site that has nanotechnology as a subject. So, where do I ask?

**Question:**

> Creating chains of ferromagnetic iron molecules connected by string or fiber in the following format:
> [image]

Comment: What aspect of nanotechnology do you want to ask about? It would be much clearer if you added a sample question of the kind you want to ask.

Comment: If you're creating a fictional world for a game/story using Nano-tech, then [worldbuilding.se] might work for you. Depends on the question you want to ask, please clarify.

Comment: I added my question. I want an engineering answer, not a fictional answer.

Comment: What is the question in your question? It looks like a statement to me

Comment: Don't be mistaken about worldbuilding, we answer questions using cutting edge science. Having said that, it looks like your issue is more pure physics without worldbuilding context (also it's not clear what the question actually is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the subject of your question is on-topic at [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). Here are the two relevant tags that I found:

- [`[nanoscience]`](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanoscience):

  > The study of the performance of ultra-small structures, materials, and devices, usu. usually 0.1 to 100 nm; also, the study of manipulating materials on an atomic or molecular scale. **Nanoscience is sometimes used interchangably with Nanotechnology, which is the manipulation of matter on an atomic and molecular scale**.

  (emphasis mine)
- [`[ferromagnetism]`](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ferromagnetism)

  This one does not have usage guidance but a quick look at the questions in the tag shows that it's probably relevant to your question.

Of course, it's advised to go through their [Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) to make sure your question is, in fact, [on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and meets the expectations of a [good question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In the interest of completeness there are a few sites for nanotech: https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/are-micro-and-nanotechnology-related-questions-on-topic  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/nanotechnology/info  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/nanotechnology/info   https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/nanotechnology/info - Engineering and Chemistry are directly relevant to this question, but your suggestion of Physics is sufficient that I'll offer this as a suggestion for improvement (completeness) rather than a competing answer.

Comment: There is lots of nanotechnology in Chemistry, to be sure, but it is not an appropriate site for the specific question that is described here.